# How to Mock private method which is called from the constructor using PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock

Example of the problem:

```
class ToBeTested {
    private MyResource myResource;
    public toBeTested() {
        this.myResource = getResource();
    }

    private MyResource getResource() {
        //Creating My Resource using information form a DB
        return new MyResource(...);
    }
}
```

I would like to mock the `getResource()` so I would be able to provide a mock instance of `MyResource`. All the examples I found on how to mock a private method are based on first creating the `ToBeTested` instance and then replace the function but since it's being called from the constructor in my case it's to late.

Is it possible to mock the private function to all instances in advance of creating them?

Comment: Why not mock the dependency (whichever it is) that accesses the DB from inside the `getResource()` method? That way, there would be no need to mock a `private` method.

Comment: `MyResource()` may be used by other class of the code and I wouldn't want to change their behaviour.

Comment: Hmm, but so what if it is used by other class? Why should that prevent the test from mocking the dependency which creates `MyResource` from a DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly but, you can [suppress](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior) and then simulate with power mockito

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(ToBeTested .class)
    public class TestToBeTested{

    @before
    public void setup(){
      suppress(method(ToBeTested.class, "getResource"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod(){
        doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
      @Override
      public MyResource answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
           return new MyResource();
      }
 }).when(ToBeTested.class, "getResource");
    }

       ToBeTested mock = mock(ToBeTested.class);
       mock.myMethod();
       //assert
    }
```

Comment: This code has an error. `mock.myMethod();` needs to be inside a function and it's not.